# Print several different pages PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I want to have a button "Print all reports" which will print 5 different URLs at once. Is there a way to do it without making it redirect you to a new page I will have to create with all the code again for each of the URLs and window.print() it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you have exposed is good from every angle. Have a different page which prints all code of 5 URLs and call `window.print()` function to open the print-dialog.

If not, you will have to use ajax to fetch the output of all 5 different URL's and dump it on the same page where the user clicked the button. But, I would oppose this approach since it loses the ability to go back to the page and user could be deceived if they bookmark it.

Comment: The new contents can be removed after page is sent for printing.

Answer (score 1):

Well if that's what you want, you can AJAX content of all the five pages into one page and once it's all ready, you can print the single page. If you use jQuery, it will look like this :

```
    (
  function(){
   $.ajax({url:"url1", success:function(resp){ 
    $("#mydiv").html(resp);
    //make other similar calls for rest of the pages
    //and in your last callback, call window.print()     
   });
    })();
```

Even if you don't want to use jQuery, you can do it with raw ajax.

Comment: That is a solution, but that means that from the moment the user clicks the print button he will have to wait until it loads? Most users will think they didn't click and will click again or something. About loading it even before he has the chance to click, it won't be good, because each page will load 5x slower + my basic solution is better I think.

Comment: This method will obviously minimize your amount of code. About user getting confused, yes that can be a problem. But there are so many techniques to show the nice looking "Loading..." dialog until it loads to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

using just a browser you write a script that generates 1 url out of 5 urls, and separate the html from each of the urls with this.

```
<DIV style="page-break-after:always"></DIV>
```

and then the user can just print out your 1 url and have 5 urls of information.

Comment: I think you didn't understand correctly, he wants to see 1 page at a time, but on each page he wants to have a button to print all.